# Absolute Path Css / Js

Tags: javascript, css, subdirectory

I want to include my css and js files from a subdirectory.

All the following examples don't work for me:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/../page/css/style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="www/page/css/style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/www/page/css/style.css" />

    <script src="../js/config.js"></script>

    <script src="../styles/js/config.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
```

If I want to include the files from the same directory, it works fine.

If I want to include them from the directory "styles/css/" it also doesn't work.

What is wrong with my code? Am I not able to include css and js files from a subdirectory?

Thank you for your replying!

Comment: I think you need to echo file_get_contents and file_exists function.

Comment: `include_once` cannot be used to include *.css and *.js files. Why do you want to include assets with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

may be there is no use if you use `include()` if you need then check with [file_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)
like:-

```
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
// include your file
}
```

use `<link>` for css and `<script>` tags for js
like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

and so on

for js

```
  <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to methode to define the path: relative to the actual webpage or based on the site root folder.

If you want to include it relative to the root folder you must insert `/` at beginning of the string otherwise not.

```
html
 |-pages
    |-css
    |  |-style.css
    |-page.html
```

you can use:

```
<style>
  <?php include '/pages/css/style.css';?>
  <?php include 'css/style.css'; ?>
</style>
```

(ps: you must choose between the two include rows)

Comment: how you add css and js using include and what will be functioning after

Comment: php `include` simply copy the content of the file in the webpage, so you end up with `<style> content of css file </style>`. If you want include a javascript file you should change the `<style>` tags with `<script>`